# Embed microsoft bookings Web Page with ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, outlook, embed

Is there any way to render the content of a Microsoft Booking page into my **ReactJS** application?

For example, I have found this as example (non-related, just googled).

https://microsoftbookings.azurewebsites.net/?organization=financialservices&UICulture=es-ES&CallBackURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com

[image]

This is the idea..

Basically, I have my App working, and the central zone where the page should be rendered is a div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this Post on Microsoft Forums (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/embed-booking-site-into-my-website/ce4e987f-6ba8-457f-aae2-492b8d1ee393?auth=1), where it indicates how to do this.

It works as expected.